# Write File to Sharepoint Online WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have recently been working on developing a winRT app that will allow someone to enter information on to a form. I am trying to then upload that form to SharePoint online as part of the Office 365 suite. I have been unable to find any examples or real documentation on how to do this. Has anyone found anything close to this online? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do an HTTP put from your WinRT app to your SharePoint online web services.  Here is a [list of the Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg454740%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  Here is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Metro-client-for-Web-API-664848c5) of how to call RESTful web services from a Windows Store style app.